# In Overlord, Carne Village has a big silver area towards the middle. What is it? (picture in description)

Tags: overlord

It looks kind of like a lake or a large structure. Maybe it's just an opening with stone, dirt, or clay as the ground. Do you know?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, that was a tower where the [bell](https://overlordmaruyama.fandom.com/wiki/Carne_Village) is situated.

> When the bell in the middle of the village square rang to signal noon, everyone would take a break for lunch time.

And no, that's not a lake. That's just a large open area with no structures in it apart from the bell.

Comment: Every other open area has grass. Any idea what material it is?

Comment: @DavidHobs Earth? I would have to rewatch just to be sure as it also looks like water now that I think about it.

Comment: There's another view of the village in season one and it looks a lot like sand, dirt, and/or gravel.